# deployment failure::network not supported by registrar: no network bsc found on chain ethereum

Tags: graphql, subgraph, thegraph

> × Failed to deploy to Graph node https://api.thegraph.com/deploy/:
> deployment failure::network not supported by registrar: no network bsc
> found on chain ethereum error Command failed with exit code 1. info
> Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command.

Comment: Can you share more of your setup? How are you trying to run graph-node?

Comment: The problem is that BSC is disabled in graphprotocol currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

BSC network in graph node has disabled by the graph protocol team.
Maybe, I think that they are fixing or updating something for BSC network.